# What is the replacement for cocoapods in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Since long time, we're using `cocoapods` in xcode projects.

**Is there any replacement for Cocoapods?**

Comment: I think you should post more detail about issues above. Some issues are not caused by CocoaPods. If you tell what your team want, maybe I can give you some suggestions.

Comment: You could use Carthage, Git subproject, simply copy the dependencies into your project, Swift Package manager.  Asking for off-site resource recommendations is off-topic, however

Comment: "It may have some warnings which we cannot fix, as it'll replaced on pod install." Could you define that? Because there are ways to get rid of it. "Sometime we're not getting updated pods if Swift/iOS/Xcode has been upgraded" Well, are you looking for others developers to be exactly ready on each iOS/Swift/XCode update? Do you pay them for that?

Comment: @Larme Well, Dependancy management tools is not responsible at all but we're facing these problems very oftenly with this. Thats why I came to that points listing. Anyway I'll modify my question and keeping general question to look replacement for cocoapods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one good alternative to Cocoapods i.e. **Carthage**, it is a simple dependency manager for iOS and macOS, it is developed by developers from Github.

Instead of static libraries, Carthage uses dynamic frameworks which is the only way supported for distributing apps written in Swift and supporting iOS 8.0 and above.

Carthage vs CocoaPods

- CocoaPods creates a new project when integrated and creates a new workspace which you don't need in case of Carthage.
- There is no need for centralized repository file like Podspec.(this is for the creators of the third party library).
- To use Carthage your project must support iOS 8.0 or later because it uses dynamic frameworks.
- When you install third-party libraries using Carthage, it clones each repository from Git and builds each dependency into a framework, which is used by your app.

You can find more details [here](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage).

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering, without taking account on your background, it's not directed to you especially, but to give possibles solutions and explaining a little why, and other may find this useful.

We often use `CocoaPods` for open-source code, it's "free" (note the quotes, I'm not talking about the various licences). I also use `CocoaPods` with private code in my company.

> It may have some warnings which we cannot fix, as it'll replaced on
>   pod install.

Well, you can suppress the warnings of the pods by using [`inhibit_warnings`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#inhibit_all_warnings_bang).
What can also be done? Fixing the code by doing a pull request, open an issue on the repository, etc. Is it the time when you open a ticket, and "give back" to the community?
Also, you can have a clone of the repository, use `:path =>` to point to your own clone with your own fixes (check https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod), note that it's even easier to modify the code of the different pods that way, because XCode won't trouble you with *"“MyFileInMyPod” is locked for editing and you may not be able to save your changes. Do you want to unlock it?"*.
Well, if you still want updates, I'd suggest to have a branch then, to cherry pick or stash your modifications.

> Sometime we're not getting updated pods if Swift/iOS/Xcode has been
>   upgraded.

I'm assuming that the issue is mostly linked to Swift changes, because unfortunately, and that's the reason why I didn't get into Swift personally, is because Swift changes, evolves, and between Swift 1, 2, 2.2/2.3 and 3, there are been many break changes.
When you adopt a language (and its framework), you need to take in account the possible evolutions and may adapt to them.
Now, if we are talking about the "free" (as cited previously) code, are you expecting for the developers to be up to date on each release? Many of them have "real/others" jobs and do it in their free time. 
I know there are some discussion when someone give "free code", other relies one it, then does the developer have a responsibility? Does he/she needs to keep it up to date? Fix all the issues? Does he/she needs to maintain it until he/she dies?
You have dependencies, then adapt and accept to the dependencies. It's like updating macOS and not checking if all your most loved and useful apps are compatible with the new OS version.

*Remember, even if I think that your question is a little aggressive towards a "free" tool that is quite useful and open-source code, it's not directed to you.*